# Was there ever a period in Nascent Christianity before formalized ritual or dogma?

Tags: church-history, early-church, apostolic-age

The title is pretty explicit. But further, if so, is there any reliable documentation of who the adherents were and how they comported themselves?

Comment: _Go therefore and teach all nations ... teaching them to observe all things that I have commanded you_ Matthew 28:20. The dogma and the ritual come directly from Jesus Christ himself, via the apostles whom he, himself, chose. And both come, immediately, from his lifetime on earth into the apostles' lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Was there ever a period in Nascent Christianity before formalized ritual or dogma

Christianity was born (which is what *nascent* means) out of Judaism, which possessed both rituals and dogmas; as such, as it was born, it sought to reinterpret Jewish rituals and dogmas, by turning them into Christian rituals and dogmas (e.g., the weekly Sunday gatherings are based on weekly Sabbath gatherings, and the Eucharist served therein is based on the Passover meal; Christian monotheism is based on Jewish monotheism; etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**Was there ever a period in Nascent Christianity before formalized ritual or dogma?**

I do not believe so. The Apostles of Our Lord would have certainly have laid down procedures to follow. Unfortunately, we simply do not have all the historical proofs at our disposal.

But there are glimmers in the Scriptures that seems to indicate such things.

For example, St. Paul writes the following:

> Therefore, brethren, stand fast, and hold the traditions which ye have been taught, whether by word, or our epistle. - [2 THESSALONIANS 2:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/2%20Thessalonians%202%3A15)

Certainly, some of these traditions would touch on liturgical and dogmatic topics.

The Early Church teachs that many traditions were handed down to us by the Apostles.

Comment: Before the Bible was even codified or any attempt was given as to decide what should be in it. You had apostles writing letters to the church in Corinth to formalise ritual and dogma.